# Third label in UITableViewCell has jumbled up text

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

![enter image description here][1]I'm trying to add a third label to my UITableViewCell, and initially I tried adding it to the CellForRowAtIndexPath method and that worked, but when I scrolled down and back up, the text in the third label was all jumbled up for some reason. I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController to load the cells.

Here is my code:

```
if([people count] > 0){
    user = people[0];
    }
    if(user){
        if([object objectForKey:@"itemName"]!=nil){
            cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"itemName"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.textColor = listColor;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"City: %@",[user objectForKey:@"city"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = listColor;
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:10.0f];

        UILabel *mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 50.0, 220.0, 15.0)];
        mainLabel.textColor = listColor;


        mainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:10.0f];
        //mainLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

        [mainLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[user username]] ];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];


    }
```

Any idea how to fix this? It's strictly the third label and it only happens after the user scrolls down and then scrolls back up

Comment: what exactly do you mean with jumbled?

Comment: What does the `setThirdLabel` method do? Does it call `addSubview:` to add the label? If so, you are adding more and more labels to each cell as the user scrolls.

Comment: the screen in your picture is too small, I cant see anything

Comment: the screen is not important, the text to the right of it is

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are adding the `UILabel` all the time. So when you scroll, you `UITableViewCell` is recycled and you just add another `UILabel`. The best solution is to subclass `UITableViewCell` to add your third `UILabel` in the `init` method of your subclassed `UITableViewCell`.

Another solution would be to change `setThirdLabel` to just remove the old `UILabel` before adding the new one. But yea, I recommend you to just update the text since the style is the same all the time.

**EDIT: An example** (untested, just to get the idea)

The .h file:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    @private
        UILabel *anotherLabel;
}

- (void)setAnotherLabelText:(NSString *)text;
```

The .m file:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {
        // Set up the label
        anotherLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        // Set some initial style here
        anotherLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        anotherLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed];            

        // Add the label to the cell
        [self addSubview:anotherLabel];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Dont forget this or weird things will happen
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Move your label to its final position
    anotherLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 200.0f, 30.0f);
}

- (void)setAnotherLabelText:(NSString *)text
{
    _anotherLabel.text = text;
}
```

And if you have done this, you can use code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Set up the cell
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setAnotherLabelText:@"foo"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Subclass `UILabel`? I think you meant to say subclass `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed that. :-)

Comment: hm...so in the header file of my subclass, I would put @property(strong,nonatomic) UILabel *thirdLabel; and then just initialize it the init method?

Comment: I just added an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me so far:

Without the thirdLabel there is a total of 3 subviews on the cell (an UIImageView, and two other labels)...so I said if the number of subviews cell.contentView has is less than 4, then add a subview. Otherwise, there already is a subview so do nothing

Comment: This works unless iOS10 adds another subview u dont know yet.